# Model.new is not saving associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :syllabuses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :topics, through: :syllabuses  
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :syllabuses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :syllabuses
end

class Syllabus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :topic  
end
```

i am using `topic` nested in `course` in the `routes`

Now while saving a new `topic` the following code works :-

```
 @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])    
 @topic = @course.topics.create(topic_params)
```

AND this doesnt

```
@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])    
@topic = @course.topics.new(topic_params)
@topic.save
```

The new `topic` is saved but no associations are saved in `syllabus` , i think i might need to use `build` function here, can anyone pls help ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

**Option 1**

Save the `@course` object instead of the `@topic` object. The newly created `topic` association will be inserted in to the `syllabuses` table. So you would do this instead:

```
@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])    
@topic = @course.topics.new(topic_params)
@course.save
```

**Option 2**

Create the associated topic in a different manner, like so:

```
@topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
@topic.courses << @course
@topic.save
```

Note: I obtained some information from [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346642/877472)