# Rails 6 - create has_many through record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why does the CompaniesController not create a record CompanyUser with `current_user.companies.build(company_params)`?
How can I create CompanyUser record at the time of creation of the Company record?

**Models:**

**User**

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: :company_users
end
```

**Company**

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  include Userstampable::Stampable

  has_many :company_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :company_users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_users, reject_if: :all_blank

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 1000 }
end
```

**CompanyUser**

```rb
class CompanyUser < ApplicationRecord
  include Userstampable::Stampable

  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user

  validates :company_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**CompaniesController**

```rb
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @company = current_user.companies.build(company_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @company }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def company_params
      params.require(:company).permit(:name, :description)
    end
end
```

**Migrate**

```rb
class CreateCompanyUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :company_users do |t|
      t.integer :role, default: 0
      t.belongs_to :company, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :user, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false, include_deleted_at: true
      t.userstamps index: true, include_deleter_id: true

      t.index [:company_id, :user_id], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346642

Comment: current_user.companies.build(company_params) should be create a Company with CompanyUser record?

Comment: In Rails 5+ `belongs_to` associations are non optional by default. Those two validations in CompanyUser are completely superfluous and may be the route of the problem. Also how are you actually testing this?

Comment: @max I'm creating a company in view. If I remove two validations, CompanyUser record will still not be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `:inverse_of` option on the `belongs_to` associations in CompanyUser model and remove the presence validations on `:company_id` and `:user_id` in ComapanyUser to make this work. The ComapanyUser model should look like this:

```
class CompanyUser < ApplicationRecord
  include Userstampable::Stampable

  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :company_users
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :company_users
end
```

Check the description of the `:through` option in ActiveRecord association [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options). It mentions that you need `:inverse_of` to create join model records.

> If you are going to modify the association (rather than just read from
> it), then it is a good idea to set the :inverse_of option on the
> source association on the join model. This allows associated records
> to be built which will automatically create the appropriate join model
> records when they are saved. (See the 'Association Join Models'
> section above.)