# Why isnt the join table for has_many through created in rails when using new/save versus create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

This is on rails 4.2.11.3. I have a `has_many` `through` relationship set up like this:

```
class ProgramCourse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :program
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :program_courses
  has_many :programs, -> { uniq }, through: :program_courses
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :program_courses
  has_many :courses, -> { uniq }, through: :program_courses
end
```

If I create a course like this:

```
c = program.courses.create(name: 'Amazing Course')
```

The `ProgramCourse` record is created along with the new `Course`. However, if I do so like this:

```
c = program.courses.new(name: 'Amazing Course')
c.save
```

Only the `Course` is created. Is this a bug? Is there something syntactically off with my relationship? Can anyone explain why these two are different?

Comment: Does it work if you use "build" instead of "new" on the second example? Sometime ago they used to be different methods, I'm not sure for ROR4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using has\_many :through and build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346261/using-has-many-through-and-build)

Answer (score -2):

```rb
class ProgramCourse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :program
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :program_courses
  has_many :programs, -> { uniq }, through: :program_courses
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :program_courses
  has_many :courses, -> { uniq }, through: :program_courses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :program_courses, :courses
end
```

You need to add this in the model to use this or you can use the build method to create the associated record

```rb
c = program.courses.build(name: 'Amazing Course')
c.save
```